# call onGenerateRoute function without arguments

Tags: flutter, navigation, arguments

I wonder how we can call generateRoute without arguments
onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute

my expectation would be:
RouteGenerator.generateRoute(settings)

Thanks,

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: NumberCreator().stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print('StreamBuilder: ${snapshot.connectionState}');

          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Demo',
            **onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,**
            onGenerateInitialRoutes: (String initialRouteName) {
              return [
                RouteGenerator.generateRoute(
                    RouteSettings(name: '/', arguments: snapshot)),
              ];
            },
          );
        });
  }
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        if (args is AsyncSnapshot<int>) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really that you are calling `onGenerateRoute` without arguments, it is because you are passing a parameters which comply to the expected type `RouteFactory` [defined as follow in the flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteFactory.html):

```dart
typedef RouteFactory = Route<dynamic>? Function(RouteSettings settings);
```

And your `generateRoute` comply to this type as it is a function which takes a `RouteSettings` parameter and returning an object of type `Route<dynamic>`.

Here is the code I've used in my projects:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      initialRoute: /*<my_initial_route */,
      onGenerateRoute: MyRouter.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      // your cases ...
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```